# Fill in symbols for legend, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Hello all and thanks in advance,

I am trying to have my legend show filled shapes, opposed to simply outlining with color (shown below):

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
    p.ch4 <- ggplot(ch4.data, aes(x=date, y=value, group = type, 
                            fill=type, color=type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type), color = "black", size =4) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type, color=type), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorchid3","indianred3","dodgerblue3")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorchid3","indianred3","dodgerblue3")) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=as.POSIXct("2017-11-09"), xmax=as.POSIXct("2018-04-09"),ymin=0,ymax=75,alpha=.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')))) +
  labs(y = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')), x = "", color = "", shape = "") +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18) +
  #theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

print(p.ch4)
```

I realize I have done a lot of work regarding datapoint colors, outlines, and shapes, and I wondered if therein lies my issue?

For reproducibility, here is my dataset "ch4.data":

```
> dput(ch4.data)
structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("SWI", 
"4cm", "12cm"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1537167600, 
1535266800, 1533279600, 1531292400, 1529305200, 1527318000, 1526713200, 
1527231600, 1525762800, 1524294000, 1522825200, 1521356400, 1516089600, 
1511596800, 1509606000, 1537340400, 1534575600, 1531119600, 1530255600, 
1527663600, 1525071600, 1517212800, 1513756800, 1510300800, 1537167600, 
1535094000, 1533020400, 1530946800, 1528873200, 1528441200, 1526713200, 
1524898800, 1522393200, 1519545600, 1516435200, 1514361600, 1510992000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(52.43, 
40.37, 12.92, 5.12, 4.93, 2.4, 1.97, 3.07, 5.7, 3.56, 2.74, 0.67, 
0.78, 0.48, 0.7, 0.3, 0.21, 4.11, 1.54, 4.86, 7.42, 3.62, 0.81, 
0.37, 6.2, 9.14, 34.11, 57.83, 63.02, 63.56, 54.13, 42.92, 32.59, 
23.23, 9.97, 5.62, 0.52), geochem = c("ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4")), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved like so. Important step was to give all three scales the same name so that the legends are merged into one:

BTW: I also dropped the second geom_point layer and simply added the black color as an argument.

EDIT: As @chemdork123 correctly pointed out in his comment, the issue could have been more easily be solved by setting the same labels for all three scales in the `labs()` statement or by dropping the empty, i.e. `""` labels for the `color` and `shape` scales.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ch4.data, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=type)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type, fill=type), color = "black", size=4) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "type", values = c(21:23)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "type", values = c("darkorchid3","indianred3","dodgerblue3")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "type", values = c("darkorchid3","indianred3","dodgerblue3")) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=as.POSIXct("2017-11-09"), xmax=as.POSIXct("2018-04-09"),ymin=0,ymax=75,alpha=.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')))) +
  labs(y = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')), x = "", color = "", shape = "") +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18) +
  #theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Same idea would be to add `fill=""` to the `labs()` in OP's code.  Interestingly, including the empty strings for `labs()` does not seem to interfere here, because the `scale_*` functions override the `labs()` functions.  So no matter what you put for `color=`, `fill=` and `shape=` within `labs()`, they will all still get labeled according to `scale_*_manual()` if you specify title there.

Comment: @chemdork123 Thanks. That was indeed the main issue with the code. I've overlooked that.